# Тире при пояснении

Tags: пунктуация, тире, бсп

**Вместо этого, вам нужно давать конкретику — говорить, что надо делать, и показывать, как это надо делать.**

Правомерно ли здесь поставить тире? Если да, то на основании какого правила? В такой ситуации говорится только про приложения, про инфинитивы нигде не говорится.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Давать конкретику — это **обобщающее слово**, говорить и показывать — **однородные члены.**

Основной формой считается **двоеточие**, но оно может заменяться **тире**.

Вариант 1. Вместо этого, вам нужно **давать конкретику: говорить**, что надо делать, **и показывать**, как это надо делать  (однородный ряд в пояснительной конструкции).

Вариант 2. Вместо этого, вам нужно **давать конкретику** — **говорить**, что надо делать, **и показывать,** как это надо делать (однородный ряд в присоединительной конструкции).

Розенталь: http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=103#pp103

Если однородные члены предложения носят характер приложения  или уточнения, то после обобщающего слова вместо двоеточия может ставиться тире.

Comment: Jasmin, а как Вы считаете: нужна ли запятая после "вместо этого"? Мне кажется, что нет.

Comment: У Лопатина: http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=122#pp122  Примечание 2. Оборот с предлогом вместо, имеющий значение замещения, может включать существительные, обозначающие действия или предметы. В первом случае оборот всегда выделяется запятыми, во втором — обособление необязательно. Ср. примеры: Вместо ответа, он начал толкать меня головой в грудь (М. Г.). — Вместо шляпы он купил себе старую-фуражку (М. Г.) (значения: не ответил, а начал толкать; купил фуражку, а не шляпу);

Comment: Здесь, скорее всего, "вместо общих слов надо давать конкретику", тогда обособление факультативное и   необязательное. В Нацкорпусе этот оборот обычно не обособляется.

Comment: @Jasmin Контекст: "Вы должны стараться, чтобы контент был без воды и лирики". Во время заключительной редактуры я всё же убрал запятую после "вместо этого": без запятой выглядит естественнее, даже интонационно там нет паузы.

Comment: Да, это правильное решение.

Comment: А разве обобщающее слово и однородные члены могут быть инфинитивами? Ни разу не встречал подобных примеров. Может в случае с двоеточием это скорее БСП, где второе предложение неполное?

Comment: Настоящий мужчина должен в своей жизни сделать три вещи: построить дом, посадить дерево и родить сына».